# How should I fix my fstab

Tags: fstab

I got 2 partition I want to mount

```
sdb1 which uses ext2 file system
sdc1 which uses ext4 file system
```

I added this 2 line on fstab

```
/dev/sdb1 /home2 auto auto,noatime,default 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /home3 auto auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,default 0 0
```

Looks like it's not correct because I fail to mount. How to correct it?

Yet I can't mount them due to some error.

This is my fstab and some command to show that

```
root@host [/etc]# cat fstab
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Jan 8 10:16:53 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=eb3b9431-7964-47fd-a497-e4ddcd3f9d05 / ext4 defaults 1 1
UUID=ed11681c-9343-41ac-ac8b-a29bf4d13fbd /boot ext4 defaults 1 2
#UUID=191a3af4-c48a-4779-974a-c55dc290543d /home1 ext4 defaults 1 2
#UUID=eca46a9a-6666-40d0-bbe5-e35b54295264 /home2 ext4 defaults 1 2
UUID=475f3ba3-6459-42ac-b441-1daa95acb2b3 swap swap defaults 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/usr/tmpDSK /tmp ext3 defaults,noauto 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /home2 auto auto,noatime,default 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /home3 auto auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,default 0 0
root@host [/etc]# parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD15EADS-00R (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
1 1049kB 525MB 524MB primary ext4 boot
2 525MB 34.4GB 33.8GB primary linux-swap(v1)
3 34.4GB 1500GB 1466GB primary ext4


Model: ATA SAMSUNG SSD 830 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
1 1049kB 256GB 256GB primary ext2


Model: ATA M4-CT256M4SSD2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
1 1049kB 256GB 256GB primary ext4


root@host [/etc]# mount /home2
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so

root@host [/etc]# mount /home3
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so

root@host [/etc]#
```

Comment: please give the output of `dmesg | tail` when you try to `mount`

Comment: And what is at the end of the kernel logs (just use the exact command `mount` is suggesting) after the failed mounts?

Comment: how to get the end of the kernel logs?

Comment: root@host [/etc]# dmesg | tail
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120
IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if I should delete this question. The problem is I use `default` while I should have written `defaults`. It's too localized I guess.

Comment: too localized gets my vote.

Comment: It does appear as if the missing 's' at the end of 'default' would be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yea that fixed it. Should I let the question stay? There are other answers. In stackoverflow this questions like this are okay. Deleted questions may make everyone look bad.

Comment: Don't delete it. SOmeone might stumble over this and he or she could use that information :)

Comment: Mark this as answer. But look at my comment to mdpc's answer. You should not use `auto`.

Comment: why not? What's wrong with noauto

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/dev/sdb1 /home2 ext2 auto,noatime,defaults 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /home3 ext4 auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults 0 0
```

'auto' (as you originally had it in your /etc/fstab entries) is not a valid filesystem type.

Comment: `auto` is a special filesystem-type, but that is intended for other filesystems (`man mount` to see details afaik).

Comment: Not in the various `man fstab` pages that I am aware of.

Comment: no mdpc. It should be auto. And it's working now.

Comment: From `man mount` on CentOS5:
`The auto type may be useful for user-mounted floppies.  Creating a file /etc/filesystems can be useful to change the probe order (e.g., to try vfat before msdos or ext3 before ext2) or if you use a kernel module autoloader.  Warning:
              the probing uses a heuristic (the presence of appropriate ‘magic’), and could recognize the wrong  filesystem  type, possibly with catastrophic consequences. If your data is valuable, don’t ask mount to guess.`

Comment: The last statement however says it all...